# Oracle - SQL query to bin the data from one table to another based on a column value?

Tags: sql, oracle

What SQL query to use to generate `Table2` from `Table1`(tables shown below)?

`Table2` needs to bin the timestamps from `Table1` into start and end times according to the `Table1.Status` field. As a result `Table2.Status` should toggle between 0 and 1 in every row.

`Table2.StartTime` = 1st value of `Table1.TimeStamp` whenever `Table1.Status` changes from 1 to 0 or viceversa.

`Table2.EndTime` = (1st value of `Table1.TimeStamp` of `Table1.Status` next change) - 1millisecond

The first record in `Table1` can start from any `Status` - 1 or 0.

```
Table1

TimeStamp                               Status
11-NOV-11 12.45.45.445000000 AM           1
11-NOV-11 12.46.45.445000000 AM           1
11-NOV-11 12.47.45.445000000 AM           1
11-NOV-11 12.48.45.445000000 AM           0
11-NOV-11 12.49.45.445000000 AM           0
11-NOV-11 12.50.45.445000000 AM           1
11-NOV-11 12.51.45.445000000 AM           0
11-NOV-11 12.52.45.445000000 AM           0
11-NOV-11 12.53.45.445000000 AM           1
...
```

```
Table2

StartTime                                        EndTime                     Status
11-NOV-11 12.45.45.445000000 AM      11-NOV-11 12.48.45.444000000 AM            1
11-NOV-11 12.48.45.445000000 AM      11-NOV-11 12.50.45.444000000 AM            0
11-NOV-11 12.50.45.445000000 AM      11-NOV-11 12.51.45.444000000 AM            1
11-NOV-11 12.51.45.445000000 AM      11-NOV-11 12.53.45.444000000 AM            0
...
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
select min(t2.TimeStamp) Start_time
  , lead(min(t2.TimeStamp), 1)over(order by min(t2.TimeStamp))  - INTERVAL '0.001' SECOND End_time
  , t2.status
from (
  select t1.TimeStamp TimeStamp, STATUS, group_tag, first_value(group_tag ignore nulls)over(order by t1.TimeStamp ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) group_tag_gap_filling
  from (
      select t.TimeStamp, Status, case when lead(status, 1, 2)over(order by t.TimeStamp) != status then row_number()over(order by t.TimeStamp)end group_tag
      from Table1 t
    )t1
  )t2
group by t2.group_tag_gap_filling, t2.status
;
```

First, in inline view "t1", I create temporary groups
Then Secondly, I fill in the gap for all temporary groups
Then I extract what is need using min aggregation function, and lead analytic function, and I extract 0.001 second from end_time

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps and islands problem, with a slight twist.  The twist being that you don't want to report the most recent timestamp record for each island, but rather you want to report the record immediately following *after* that most recent record.  So, we can use the difference in row numbers method, and also compute the lead of the timestamp column.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ts) rn1,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Status ORDER BY ts) rn2,
                LEAD(ts) OVER (ORDER BY ts) AS ts_lead
    FROM Table1 t
)

SELECT MIN(ts) AS StartTime, MAX(ts_lead) AS EndTime
FROM cte
GROUP BY Status, rn1 - rn2
HAVING MAX(ts_lead) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY MIN(ts);
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using the `analytical` functions and `GROUP BY` as follows:

```
SELECT MIN(TIMESTAMP) AS STARTTIME, MAX(TIMESTAMP) AS ENDTIME, STATUS 
  FROM
       (SELECT T.TIMESTAMP, T.STATUS, SUM(CHANGE_POINT) OVER (ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) AS SM 
          FROM
               (SELECT T.TIMESTAMP, T.STATUS, 
                       CASE WHEN LAG(STATUS) OVER (ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) <> STATUS THEN 1 END AS CHANGE_POINT
                  FROM YOUR_TABLE T
                ) T
        )
GROUP BY SM, STATUS
```

You can also use the `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` clause as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE
MATCH_RECOGNIZE
(
 ORDER BY TIMESTAMP
  MEASURES
    FIRST( TIMESTAMP ) AS STARTDATE,
    LAST( TIMESTAMP ) AS ENDDATE,
    FIRST( STATUS ) AS STATUS
  ONE ROW PER MATCH
  PATTERN( same_field+ )
  DEFINE same_field AS FIRST(STATUS) = STATUS 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve gaps-and-islands problems.  In this case, the simplest method is two window functions and filtering:

```
select status, ts as start_time, lead(ts) over (order by ts) as end_time
from (select t1.*, lag(status) over (order by ts) as prev_status
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
where prev_status is null or prev_status <> status
order by start_time;
```

The logic is simple:

- Keep each row where the status changes, filtering out all other rows.
- Use `lead()` to get the ending timestamp.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=50158c1604821dc9df68d61dbacb67e5) is a db<>fiddle.